# How to move an object based on sound frequency?

Tags: c#, api, audio, action

Is anybody able to help to me to find the solutions to convert sound to action based on the vibration of the frequency signal, I need to make an object move on PC... Any suggestions about the API that supports this? Thanks.

Comment: [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is often the API quoted when people ask questions like this.  Never tried it myself.

Comment: You need to give more detail in your question. What do you mean by the "vibration of the frequency signal"? Are you talking about the fundamental frequency (FO) of the audio signal? Also you tagged the question C#, can I assume you don't want a C or C++ solution?